# Selenium Webdriver clicks element before Javascript has loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, webdriver

I am writing some automated tests in Selenium 2.0 using the Firefox driver. The site uses many bindings, for example an 'input' tag with a 'data-val-method-to-execute' attribute which triggers a javascript function.

Some 10% of my tests fail randomly because the driver clicks an element before the corresponding javascript function got loaded - so nothing will happen.

One solution could be Thread.Sleep - problems are: I would have to implement in all of my tests(quite a lot). They will slow my tests drastically, and time is an issue. A simple dropdown with a sleep of 1 second doesn't always work (so I would have to increase the timeout)

Comment: Are you making use of the `ExpectedConditions` class alongside `WebdriverWait` class?

Comment: I don't use ExpectedConditions because the driver successfully finds the elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to figure out a way to make Selenium wait until the page is ready. There is no "one size fits all" solution for this. It really depends on what you do.

For some complex AJAX/JavaScript, I had to use phantomjs and add code which counts the number of open/active network connections. The test would wait until the number changes (so I know the AJAX request has been sent) and then until the number of active connections drops back to 0 (so I know the AJAX is completed).

Alternatively, try to add a hidden DIV to the page which tells the test "all scripts have finished". Wait for the DIV to appear. The problem here is to make sure that your AJAX handlers create the DIV.

In order to avoid polluting your code, use an empty function which creates the DIV and insert an additional `<script>` element in the head when running the tests which overwrites the function.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron, I will implement your hidden DIV solution and make some tests. As for AJAX requests, they don't pose an issue because I am able to wait with webdriver for specific elements after the requests have finished. I'm sure it will come in handy in the future.